# Understanding Seaborn Boxplot With Examples

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I am trying to understand seaborn boxplot graph with some example data set. So, using "tips" data set.

```
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
```

First of all using 18 values as:

```
tips = tips[0:18]
```

Required data set is as:

```
1    8.77
2    10.27
3    10.33
4    10.34
5    14.78
6    14.83
7    15.04
8    15.42
9    16.29
10   16.99
11   18.43
12   21.01
13   21.58
14   23.68
15   24.59
16   25.29
17   26.88
18   35.26
```

Required graph is as:

[image]

To get good understanding I calculated Q1, Q2 and Q3 by myself.

```
Q2(Median): 16.64

Q1 Data:
9 values
[8.77, 10.27, 10.33, 10.34, 14.78, 14.83, 15.04, 15.42, 16.29]
Q1 Median: 14.78

Q3 Data:
9 values
[16.99, 18.43, 21.01, 21.58, 23.68, 24.59, 25.29, 26.88, 35.26]
Q3 Median: 23.68

Min: 8.77
Max: 35.26
Interquartile Range(IQR): 8.9

Five Number Summary:
8.77, 14.78, 16.64, 23.68, 35.26
```

So far it is looking very convincing as five number summary is matching with graph. Now I am adding one more element in this data set using:

```
tips = tips[0:19]
```

New value is `16.97` Now lots of things are going to change.
Updated Data Set is as:

```
1    8.77
2    10.27
3    10.33
4    10.34
5    14.78
6    14.83
7    15.04
8    15.42
9    16.29
10   16.97
11   16.99
12   18.43
13   21.01
14   21.58
15   23.68
16   24.59
17   25.29
18   26.88
19   35.26
```

Now Graph is as:

[image]

To understand this graph when did manual computation then that was not convincing.

```
Q2(Median): 16.97

Q1 Data:
9 values
[8.77, 10.27, 10.33, 10.34, 14.78, 14.83, 15.04, 15.42, 16.29]
Q1 Median: 14.78

Q3 Data:
10 values (Greater than or EQUAL TO MEDIAN add here)
[16.97, 16.99, 18.43, 21.01, 21.58, 23.68, 24.59, 25.29, 26.88, 35.26]
Q3 Median: 22.63

Min: 8.77
Max: 35.26
Interquartile Range(IQR): 7.85

Five Number Summary:
8.77, 14.78, 16.97, 22.63, 35.26
```

As discussed in lot of articles whisker should be `Q3+1.5*IQR` and `Q1-1.5*IQR` but this is not happening in this case:

```
1.5*7.85 = 11.775
For whisker with Q3:
22.63 + 11.775 = 34.405
```

So, on right side of graph whisker should go at max `34.405` but it is ending at `27 approx`. I need to understand this point how it is calculating this value? OR I have made any mistake in my manual calculation? Thanks

Comment: That doesn't look like the tips dataset at all.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. The plot with `whis=1`, `whis=1.5` and `whis=1.6` are identical. `whis=1.7` does the same as `whis=2`.

Comment: Wait, no. The whisker extends until the greatest data point lesser or equal to `Q3 + whis * IQR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docstring is a bit misleading. The whiskers do not extend to the calculated values but just enough to contain all the points between them (the points that are not outliers). In this case it is 26.88 since 35.26 is an outlier (beyond `Q3 + 1.5 * IQR`).

Comment: This is looking convincing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your second plot there are ouliers, which affect the calculation.

From the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html#seaborn.boxplot), you could look into the parameter `whis`:

> whis : float, optional
>
> Proportion of the IQR past the low and high quartiles to extend the plot whiskers.
>
> Points outside this range will be identified as outliers.

Try with big values for `whis` (`2.0`, `5.0`, `10.0`, ...), so that your data points always fall into the quartiles.

Comment: Basically question is about length of whisker. @Goyo answer is looking very convincing.